# Get local img from js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, create-react-app

I am using this js file

```
export const sliderData = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Horse",
        "brand": "Ferrrari",
        "img": "https://www.formula1.com/content/dam/fom-website/manual/Misc/2022manual/WinterFebruary/RedBullRB18/SI202202090260_hires_jpeg_24bit_rgb.jpg.transform/9col/image.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Power",
        "brand": "Red Bull",
        "img": './redbull.jpg'
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Arrow",
        "brand": "Mercades",
        "img": "src/images/merc.jpg"
    }
]
```

And in my react, after mapping through them, I wanted to render them as `{team.img}` but only the first only is loading.

My folder structure is as follow:

```
src
|_data
| |_teams.js
|
|_images
| |_redbull.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to place each image in the `public` folder and use only paths inside of this folder.

`create-react-app` doesn't serve images from outside this folder.

Comment: to continue on Konrad's answer, you can load the image from the public folder like this

`<img src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/image.jpg`} />`

Comment: After I shifted the images to public folder. It works. Thanks